# display image in panel (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile app using jquery mobile. I want to display an image in a panel along with a description and a title.

The title and description and the image are defined in JSON file like next :

```
var GpsData = [
    {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Sahrij",
        "latitude": "34.046902",
        "longitude": "-4.9963",
        "altitude": "384",
        "description": ".....",
        "type": "medersa",
        "image": "assets/imgs/sud.jpg"
    }
```

In JS file I defined the ids :

```
$("#poi-detail-title").html(marker.poiData.title);
$("#poi-detail-image").html("<img src='" + marker.poiData.image + "'/>");
$("#poi-detail-description").html(marker.poiData.description);
```

The title and description are working fine but the image is not displayed :(

```
<div data-role="content">
    <!-- title -->
    <h3 id="poi-detail-title"></h3>

    <!-- description -->
    <h4 id="poi-detail-description"></h4>

    <!-- distance -->
    <h4>Distance: <a id="poi-detail-distance"></a></h4>
    <!-- image don't think is correct!!!!-->
    <div id="poi-detail-image"><img></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing the error is in the content div !!!

Comment: Does it show the value of the variable if you `alert()` it

Comment: Thanks i did alert() it and i found the probleme. I wrote a wrong link to my pictures the issue is solved!